# Calculating the Z-Score

Tags: python, data-science

I want to detect the outliers in my data which is stored in a dataframe and replace the outliers with nan. If there is any other method to do this that would helpful

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
def detect_outliers(data):
    threshold=3
    mean=np.mean(data)
    std=np.std(data)

    for j in data:
        for i in range(0,len(data)):
            z_score=(j-mean)/std
            if np.abs(z_score)>threshold:
            df[data].iloc[i]=np.nan

outlier_pt=detect_outliers(df['custAge'])
```

Here is the error I am getting:
error:

```
    <ipython-input-41-fe7b061fc791> in <module>
      ----> 1 outlier_pt=pd.DataFrame(detect_outliers(df['custAge']))

     <ipython-input-40-3d36fd2341a6> in detect_outliers(data)
      8             z_score=(j-mean)/std
      9             if np.abs(z_score)>threshold:
       ---> 10                 df[data].iloc[i]=np.nan
      11 
      12 

      ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in 



__getitem__(self, key)
  2932                 key = list(key)
2933             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1,
2934                                                    raise_missing=True)
2935 
2936         # take() does not accept boolean indexers




\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
1244                 raise KeyError(
1245                     u"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis}]".format(
1246                         key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
1247 
1248             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([              55.0, 40.009803921568626,               42.0,\n                            55.0, 40.009803921568626,               47.0,\n                            35.0, 40.009803921568626,               28.0,\n                            46.0,\n              ...\n                            56.0,               57.0,               26.0,\n                            37.0,               35.0,               33.0,\n                            45.0,               27.0,               51.0,\n                            38.0],\n             dtype='float64', length=7414)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: PLease post the full stack trace so we can see what line the error is on. I'd guess the issue is `df[data]`. What are you expecting this to do? Also your identation is wrong, this won't run as it is.

Comment: Your `data` variable is a pandas Series. With the following line

```python
df[data].iloc[i]=np.nan
```

you are trying to access a DataFrame using the Series.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I am not sure you need the loops for calculating z_score

```
df['z_data'] = df['data'] - df['data'].mean() / df['data'].std(ddof=0)
df.loc[df['z_data'].abs() > threshold, 'z_data'] = np.nan
```